# Laravel: How can i sorting data using ajax in datatables?

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable

I am getting data of invoice table but i want to sort data in desc 
This is my code:

```
var oTable = $('#ks-datatable').DataTable({
    'processing': false,
    'serverSide': true,
    "searching": false,
    /*"bLengthChange": false,*/
    'ajax': '{{route('invoice.index')}}',

    columns: [
        {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        {data: 'client_name', name: 'client_name'},
        {data: 'invoice_number', name: 'invoice_number'},
        {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
        {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
        {data: 'amount', name: 'amount'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', searchable: false},
    ]
});
```

Comment: you'll probably need to sort this in the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use order in datatable :

```
 "ordering":'true'
 "order": [columnNumber, 'orderType'],
```

Example

```
 ....
 "ordering":'true'
 "order": [0, 'desc'],
```

Your code will be:

```
var oTable = $('#ks-datatable').DataTable({
    'processing': false,
    'serverSide': true,
    "searching": false,
    /*"bLengthChange": false,*/
    'ajax': '{{route('invoice.index')}}',
    "ordering":'true',
    "order": [0, 'desc'],
    columns: [
        {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        {data: 'client_name', name: 'client_name'},
        {data: 'invoice_number', name: 'invoice_number'},
        {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
        {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
        {data: 'amount', name: 'amount'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', searchable: false},
    ]
});
```